# onbeforeunload на мобильных браузерах

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем привет!

На мобильных браузерах (тестировал на Safari) не работает событие onbeforeunload. Как его заставить работать?

Вообще, задача стоит удержать пользователя на странице, поэтому необязательно именно это событие

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "123";
}
```

Comment: [Safari: onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40938707/2881286)

Comment: Вот именно для этого оно и не работает.